# Show that the number of different subgraphs in $K_{10^{10},10^{10}}$ isomorphic to $K_{100,100}$ is less than $10^{2000}$.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that the number of different subgraphs in $K_{10^{10},10^{10}}$ isomorphic to $K_{100,100}$ is less than $10^{2000}$.

I got this answer:

$\binom{10^{10}}{100}$ $\binom{10^{10}}{100}$

but I don't know if it is right

Comment: Have you shown that your binomial product (it's correct) is less than $10^{2000}$? (It's very easy, by the way.)

Comment: @bof Must have copied it from the previous question asked.

Comment: sorry for confusing. I have a series of questions based on the statement in the  title so I didn't change it. I have changed the title. And I don't know how to show the binomial product is less than 10^2000. Could you give some hints?

Answer (score 1):

The product $\binom{10^{10}}{100}^2$ for the number of subgraphs is correct. To show that $\binom{10^{10}}{100}<10^{1000}$, expand it:
$$\binom{10^{10}}{100}=\frac{10^{10}(10^{10}-1)(10^{10}-2)\dots(10^{10}-99)}{100\cdot99\cdot98\dots1}<10^{10}(10^{10}-1)(10^{10}-2)\dots(10^{10}-99)<10^{10}10^{10}10^{10}\dots10^{10}=10^{1000}$$
Squaring, we have $\binom{10^{10}}{100}^2<10^{2000}$.